# How long before you get untagged for a kill in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

Sometimes your only options might be to kill yourself on a turret, monster or minion. How long from the last time an enemy attacked you until you die does it have to be for it not to count towards your enemy score? I belive it is called an execution when you do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Execution**

If a champion dies and hasn't been damaged or debuffed by another champion in the last 13 seconds, it is an execution. Otherwise, the kill is awarded to the enemy champion who last dealt damage.

Executions are generally caused by a turret, minion, or monster. An execution offers no gold but still gives experience to nearby champions on the opposite team.

Also from the [Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kill) like 2 inches further down.

So basically, if you exhaust an enemy champion at 12 seconds after the damage you dealt it gets reset. The only way for them to dive a tower or minion wave and commit suicide is if it has been **13 seconds** since any enemy has inflicted any kind of debuf or damage.

Comment: I don't know if it's different on Howling Abyss, but I died to a super minion 12 seconds after a Vi died (hitting me), and she got the kill. I had 2 stacks of devastating blow on me when she died, lasting 3 seconds more - so it seems like it is 10 seconds after the player-caused debuff _fades_ and not 10 seconds after it's _cast_.

Comment: This is time out of combat, I believe?  So, you have to drop minion/monster/pet aggro in addition to debuffs.

Answer (score 3):

Short Answer 10 seconds;

- Assist is when you helped the Killer kill a champion with heal or
  buff or de-buffs or damage.
- The Killer is the person who last hit the the opponent champion.
- But when the Killer is a neutral unit like a minion, monster or a
  turret, the Killer becomes the last person that assist the kill the
  champion.

> So for example when you use Mocking Shout (Tryndamere) in an enemy
>   champion and he died for a turret (let's say he lost ALL health 100%
>   to the turret).

- If you have shouted with the last 10 seconds before the last hit
  occurs. you get the kill for yourself;
- If you have shouted AFTER 10 seconds, the kill goes to the turret
  (execute)

I Could not find a link to Mocking Shout, so here is the skill description:

> "Mocking Shout = (Active): Decreases surrounding enemy champions'
>   attack damage, and enemies with their backs turned also have their
>   movement speed reduced for 4 seconds. No cost Cooldown: 14 seconds
>   Radius: 400"

---

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Kill)
"A kill is the act of decreasing another champion's health to zero while it has no abilities to prevent death. The last player to strike the target champion is awarded with the kill, and all contributors within the last **10 seconds** are awarded with an assist."

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about the timer for the *kill*, though. Just for the *assist*.

Comment: I believe he is asking if someone inflicts *massive* damage to a giant enemy crab, then said crab runs into a tower for a suicide. How long since the last hit will the kill count or be a "executed" kill.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I interpreted that he already knew it, because you get LOTS of kills thanks to minions last hitting the opponent champion even with you dead. I took to long to correct because I was playing atm =X

Comment: LOL!!! nice -2 \o/ for a correct answer. my personal record =)