# Who gets the kill when the turret 'last hits' the champion slain?

Tags: league-of-legends

If multiple people are attacking a target(champion) and that target is also getting attacked by the turret.
What determines who gets the kill if the last hit is from the turret?

The person who does the most damage?

The person who hit as last(before the turret hit)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The kill always goes to the champion who damaged them most recently, unless 10 seconds has passed between death and champion damage, then it is an Execute and nobody gets kill credit.

This counts for champions who die by Turret, Fountain, Monsters and Minions.

Comment: Only within a certain amount of time. It's pretty generous, but there does come a point where the last champion to hit you doesn't count anymore.

Comment: Yeah, that is called an Execute, it takes 10 seconds to clear

Comment: I'm unsure since I haven't looked up the exact value, but I'm pretty sure it's closer to about 15 now.

Comment: Yeah I just did a quick google cause I didnt know the exact number anyways.  It doesnt happen very often to be honest, unless intentional (by the runner)

Comment: The countdown timer gets reset whenever a champion takes any damage, at least for turrets. I.E. if I damage an opponent and then they aggro a turret and take a while to die I still get credit. This is a very common occurrence in ARAM where it is advantageous to die by execute whenever there is a lull in the battle.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/55803/how-long-before-you-get-untagged-for-a-kill-in-league-of-legends?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

While eyeofthehawk's answer is true in the general case, there are certain cases which will award heroes a kill if they are able to buff a tower (most relevantly, Janna's E) or capture point (via Garrison).

If a tower thus empowered scores a kill, it will go to the empowering champion, rather than to an execute, even if the player has not damaged the opposing champion themselves.

Comment: If I understand you correctly. If Janna uses her E or someone uses Garrison it doesn't matter who hit before the turret killed the enemy champion? Janna will get the kill.

Comment: @Damek I believe that is correct. This was easier to see back when Fortify was a spell, since it had global range. If the Fortify-'d tower got the kill, the activator of Fortify was attributed.